# Ionic2 not recognized as external

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am installing ionic 2 on my Computer. Already installed Node js 0.12 with npm. I succeed to install ionic 2 but when I check using my cmd it just gives Error "Ionic not recognized as external command"

See screenshot below for the exact steps I took to install ionic2:

[image]

Comment: Pls do check if any of the ionic executables are installed in a subfolder, such as bin\ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify if ionic path is in your path environnement variable ?

to add it you can do that with this command :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Star\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin
```